# DoubleClick Event for ListViewItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, events

I know this was already asked a lot, but I didn't find any solution.

My `ListView` looks like this

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="ContactListView" BorderBrush="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding RosterItemX}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25">
                <Image Tag="{Binding Availability}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ContactDblClicked, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

I have my `ICommand` in my viewmodel:

```
public ICommand ContactDblClicked { get { return new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(contactDblClicked); } }
```

This event fires everytime someone double clicks into the `ListView`. Doesn't have to be on a `ListViewItem`.

I can handle the case when no `ListViewItem` is selected.
I cast `(ListView)e.Source`, and check if an Item is selected.

I need a way to check if what is double clicked is actually a `ListViewItem` and not empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by your last line *I need a way to check if what is double clicked is actually a ListViewItem and not empty space.*, but here are two suggestions:

**First, if you want to check if an item is selected in your `ListView`**:

```
private void contactDblClicked(MouseButtonEventArgs obj)
{
  var listView = obj.Source as ListView;
  if (listView != null)
  {
    if (listView.SelectedItem != null)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("item selected");
    }
    else
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("item not selected");
    }
  }
}
```

However, I think you already got that solution and if I understand your question right, you want to check if the user *actually* clicked an item (and not whitespace) even if an item is selected.

**So here is the second approach to check if an item was really clicked:**

```
private void contactDblClicked(MouseButtonEventArgs obj)
{
  if (((FrameworkElement) obj.OriginalSource).DataContext is YourRosterItemXType)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("item was *really* clicked");
  }
}
```

Where `YourRosterItemXType` is the type of your binded `RosterItemX` property. With the above code you check, if the `DataContext` of the original source of the mouse event is set to `YourRosterItemXType`. Items in your `ListView` have that `DataContext` set and so you check if that mouse event comes really from one of those list items.